# grecaptcha.render is not a function asp net updatepanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, recaptcha

Not sure why this is happening. On postback the captcha disappears so after reading some articles i have the below code which resolves the problem (captcha still displays after postback)

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=**pageLoad**&render=explicit"></script>

<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="sm1"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXXXXX"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $('.g-recaptcha').each(function (index, obj) {
             grecaptcha.render(obj, { 'sitekey': 'XXXXXXXX' });
        });
    }
</script>
```

However in the console window (Chrome) i see the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: grecaptcha.render is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> ((index):468)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at pageLoad ((index):467)
```

So changed pageLoad to onloadCallback

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"></script>
```

Which resolves the error but the captcha disappears when i click a button (validation issues on the form)?

Followed steps in these articles but not sure where im going wrong?
[noCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA disappearing in UpdatePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260259/nocaptcha-recaptcha-disappearing-in-updatepanel)
[Recaptcha in Updatepanel disappears during PostBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36909147/recaptcha-in-updatepanel-disappears-during-postback)